# C# Task ContinueWith Not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library

How to wait until a previous method completes before continuing execution?  I thought this would be easy, but it's not turning out that way.  I must be doing something really dumb even though I've read lots of examples.  In the following code, I can't let the *GetDocVM()* method execute until the *AddUserDocuments()* method finishes.  Why?  Because *GetDocVM()*  won't pull in the records that  were just added.  I inherited this code and am trying to improve it.

```
ut.ModelJSON = await Task.Run(() => _userTransactionService.ConvertToModelJson(typeof(UserDocument).Name, "", transactionDocs)).ConfigureAwait(false);
var taskReturnsVoid = Task.Run(() => _genericUploadService.AddUserDocuments(ut, docs));
List<GenericUploadDocumentViewModel> viewModel = new List<GenericUploadDocumentViewModel>();
await taskReturnsVoid.ContinueWith((t) =>
           {
                 viewModel = GetDocVM();//I EXPECTED THIS TO WAIT TO BE EXECUTED
           });
return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  //GETTING HERE TOO SOON
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using Tasks to run stuff which cannot run simultaneously.  You're just creating a lot of overhead without gaining anything.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels...This part of the codebase does a lot of document management and was coded poorly. Everything was buffering and didn't take advantage of async/await, etc. Lots of timeouts, memory issues, etc. So, I'm trying to improve it. Your point is valid

Comment: try this `Task result = Task.Factory.StartNew(call_method_here);
result.Wait();`

Comment: @Saif..."Cannot convert from void to system.action".

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce what you're seeing but why `ContinueWith` in the first place? Simply having `viewModel = GetDocVM` _after_ the `await` would accomplish what you need. Not much need for `ContinueWith` when you have `async/await`.

Comment: @JSteward...Are you saying that ContinueWith doesn't work with async/await?  Or is it redundant?

Comment: `ContinueWith` is redundant. `await taskReturnsVoid` already schedules everything following that line as a continuation that runs once the task completes. So by putting `viewModel  = GetDocVM()` after the await it's then part of the continuation that's already scheduled.

Comment: @BigDaddy ContinueWith works just fine but it's redundant here. `await Task.Run` is wasteful as well. Why start *another* thread just to block the current one? You end up causing an additional delay instead of running anything in the background. Web requests are already server by separate threads

Comment: @BigDaddy why use `ContinueWith` though, instead of `await taskReturnsVoid ;var viewModel = await Task.Run(()=>GetDocVM());` ? Did you run into a problem with `GetDocVM()` and thought `ContinueWith` would make a difference?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos...The problem was a mix of sync and async code in the same calls - inherited code.  I update to async all the way.  Works nicely now.  I never used ContinueWith and misundserstood its purpose.  Good learning experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't envy you as this looks an awfully bad code base, just these several lines suffer from multiple problems.

One of the biggest ones is that you shouldn't run CPU-bound work using *Task.Run* on ASP.NET. This is [what Stephen Cleary writes about this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx):

> Async and await on ASP.NET are all about I/O. They really excel at reading and writing files, database records, and REST APIs. However, they’re not good for CPU-bound tasks. You can kick off some background work by awaiting Task.Run, but there’s no point in doing so. In fact, that will actually hurt your scalability by interfering with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics. If you have CPU-bound work to do on ASP.NET, your best bet is to just execute it directly on the request thread. As a general rule, don’t queue work to the thread pool on ASP.NET.

(I recommend reading [his articles](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) as it's an excellent source of the async/await knowledge.)

So your code cleaned up:

```
ut.ModelJSON = _userTransactionService.ConvertToModelJson(typeof(UserDocument).Name, "", transactionDocs);
_genericUploadService.AddUserDocuments(ut, docs);
List<GenericUploadDocumentViewModel> viewModel = GetDocVM();
return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

However, I suspect that *_genericUploadService.AddUserDocuments* and *GetDocVM* do some I/O related work (like networking or DB access). If you want to improve the performance of your code, you should consider rewriting them as async, then you can have this:

```
ut.ModelJSON = _userTransactionService.ConvertToModelJson(typeof(UserDocument).Name, "", transactionDocs);
await _genericUploadService.AddUserDocumentsAsync(ut, docs);
List<GenericUploadDocumentViewModel> viewModel = await GetDocVMAsync();
return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Nice response, but doesn't address why ContinueWith isn't behaving like I expect.  Are my expectations flawed?

Comment: Awaiting ContinueWith must behave as you expected. I don't know how come you observed it doesn't. You can verify this for yourself by running [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/adams85/4c59deedc1a1f4f48a3ece52a2a9e3d9). Run and wait 5 secs.

Comment: The code-base is a mix of sync and async.  I made all these calls "async all the way" and it now works as intended as as you described.  I never used ContinueWith, so this has been a learning experience.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad I could help.